# setuptools is on v3.3 inside Dockerfile but actually is on v20.7.0

Tags: docker

I'm running the following commands inside Ubuntu 16.04:

```
git clone git@github.com:liveblog/liveblog.git
cd liveblog
docker build .
```

This gives me the following output:

```
[.....]
Downloading/unpacking jmespath>=0.7.1,<1.0.0 (from boto3>=1.1.4,<1.5->Superdesk-Core->-r /tmp/requirements.txt (line 10))
  Downloading jmespath-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking cryptography>=2.1.4 (from pyOpenSSL->flask-sentinel>=0.0.4,<0.1->Superdesk-Core->-r /tmp/requirements.txt (line 10))
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/setup.py) egg_info for package cryptography
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/setup.py", line 28, in <module>
        "cryptography requires setuptools 18.5 or newer, please upgrade to a "
    RuntimeError: cryptography requires setuptools 18.5 or newer, please upgrade to a newer version of setuptools
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography/setup.py", line 28, in <module>

    "cryptography requires setuptools 18.5 or newer, please upgrade to a "

RuntimeError: cryptography requires setuptools 18.5 or newer, please upgrade to a newer version of setuptools

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /tmp && pip3 install -U -r /tmp/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Checking the installed version of setuptools via `pip3 list` and `pip list` returns:

```
[...]
setuptools (20.7.0)
[...]
```

I added the following line into the `Dockerfile` right before `RUN cd /tmp && pip3 install -U -r /tmp/requirements.txt`:

```
RUN pip3 list
```

and then when I run docker build . again I get the following output:

```
Step 20/27 : RUN pip3 list
 ---> Running in 391e5e5e490b
chardet (2.2.1)
colorama (0.2.5)
html5lib (0.999)
lxml (3.3.3)
pip (1.5.4)
requests (2.2.1)
setuptools (3.3)
six (1.5.2)
urllib3 (1.7.1)
```

Why is setuptools now on `v3.3` and how am I able to save this behavior?

Comment: Could you please share your Dockerfile that you are using to build images ?

Comment: This is the Dockerfile: https://github.com/liveblog/liveblog/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you must have been checking setup tools on your host-machine, that says (20.7.0) , 
 however it should have been upgraded inside Docker-Image. (Inside your docker images as you said it is : 3.3.

Try replacing your instructions with this one or may be anything that is more suitable.

```
#> RUN cd /tmp && pip3 install -U setuptools && pip3 list && pip3 install -U -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

This will resolve the current issue that is related to setuptools version.